# Java: Unit testing image manipulations

Tags: java, unit-testing, image, image-processing

I have a method that deals with an image. The method takes one image, performs some manipulations over it and returns another image:

```
public BufferedImage manipulateImage (Image image) {
    ...
}
```

I'm not sure if there are any best practices of writing unit tests for such activities. What characteristics of the image should be checked at a first place? How to check if the image was not spoiled? For instance, once I faced a problem when GIF images became color-inverted after reading them with `ImageIO` and saving back.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Get your original image (`x`), run the transform and save the manipulated image (`y`), physically check yourself that `y` is what you want to test.  Your test is then that `F(x) = y`, if you have both `x` and `y` in your `src/test/resources` directory you can compare `y` to the output of your test.

You may also be interested in http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/ (C++ not Java) should you not need to test for 100% equality.

**Edit**: also see this question - [Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm)