# C# image analysis library

Tags: c#, .net, image, image-processing

I have to develop a small application that gets some images and then counts the items in the image. It is something like a satellite image with a road and I need to count the cars.

Can you give me some hints where to start? I am completely lost.

Thanks a lot, 
Radu

Comment: Do you want to find a library, or are you writing your own?  There's some help here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have you checked out [OpenCV](http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/)? [Emgu CV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) provides the .NET bindings

Answer (score 2):

**Image processing library:**

OpenCV or if you have Matlab with the image processing toolbox it would be very nice.

**Algorithm wise**

Counting cars on a road is not as simple as it appears. Lets suppose they have a invariant scale (say 1.0).

1. Create yourself a Hough transform algo to vote for rectangles with about the same width and height as your cars.
2. In your vote buffer find the 'n' greatest vote scores and this is your number of cars.

This is not so complicated and OpenCV can be pretty useful. You can estimate the maximum value of your hough score for each car so you can set thresholds to skip outliers.