# Speedup Image comparison

Tags: opengl, graphics, image-processing, directx, gpu

I'm looking for an algorithm, that would do image comparisons at real time, basically on images acquired from a webcam (like 30 frames/second). My current implementation is pretty slow, tired to improve it by dropping a few frames and reducing the resolution -- but with no success.

So, I'm exploring options like using better algorithms like Key-point Matching etc. And on a different note, I'm also looking for a GPU based image comparison sample implementations (either DirectX or OpenGL APIs).

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried [Perceptual Image Diff](http://pdiff.sourceforge.net/)?

Answer (score 1):

I didn't read the entire thread but it may help you somehow

[Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm)