# Compare two images, and return the rate of similarity in %

Tags: c#, .net, image

In my project i have to compare two images, in any format(*.png, *.jpg, *.bmp etc.), and return the rate of similarity in percents.

Did anyone do this?

If yes, how?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm/844113#844113

Comment: u can also check [AForge.Imaging](http://www.aforgenet.com/projects/iplab/) decent library to work with images. in addition there's forum so u can try and ask there.

Comment: It might help if you defined "similarity" in this instance. Color, recognition, etc. all have different approaches when it comes to something being "similar".

Comment: Check out this question in related subject in Java: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8644960/java-library-to-compare-image-similarity

Answer (score 2):

If you are trying to compare an image (or part of it) with another images, I searched internet and found that leadtools has correlation functions that compare an image with all the areas of the same dimensions in another image. For more information, see this link:
http://www.leadtools.com/help/leadtools/v175/dh/po/leadtools.imageprocessing.core~leadtools.imageprocessing.core.correlationcommand.html