# Is this image similarity code thread safe?

Tags: c#, image-processing, thread-safety

I was looking for help with checking the similarity between 2 images and I came across [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6608315/compare-two-images-and-return-the-rate-of-similarity-in), which referred to [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35151067/algorithm-to-compare-two-images-in-c-sharp). While both posts have helpful information I decided to use the approach found on [this site here](https://rosettacode.org/wiki/Percentage_difference_between_images#C.23) - which is remarkably straightforward.

With this background in mind I have decided to use the below approach for comparing 2 images. My question is - should this approach scale well? By scale well I mean is it thread safe? If it is not thread safe what should I change to make it thread safe?

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;

class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap("Lenna50.jpg");
        Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap("Lenna100.jpg");

        if (img1.Size != img2.Size)
        {
            Console.Error.WriteLine("Images are of different sizes");
            return;
        }

        float diff = 0;

        for (int y = 0; y < img1.Height; y++)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < img1.Width; x++)
            {
                Color pixel1 = img1.GetPixel(x, y);
                Color pixel2 = img2.GetPixel(x, y);

                diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.R - pixel2.R);
                diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.G - pixel2.G);
                diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.B - pixel2.B);
            }
        }

        Console.WriteLine("diff: {0} %", 100 * (diff / 255) / (img1.Width * img1.Height * 3));
    }
}
```

UPDATE: Here is the updated class with the threading code. I have not used threading much. It works fine when I test locally. I am wondering if this is an okay method to use. I was also, wondering if I should use Thread.Sleep so that this thread does not block other threads.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Threading;

    public class CompareImages
    {
        public static string statusmsg = string.Empty;

        public static void CheckImages(string imagepath1, string imagepath2)
        {
            // Create thread
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => CheckImageDiff(imagepath1, imagepath2));
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join(); // Does this mean I don't have to do Thread.Sleep(__)?
        }

        public static void CheckImageDiff(string path1, string path2)
        {
            Bitmap img1 = new Bitmap(path1);
            Bitmap img2 = new Bitmap(path2);

            if (img1.Size != img2.Size)
            {
                statusmsg = "Images are of different sizes. Images should be the same size.";
            }
            else
            {
                float diff = 0;

                for (int y = 0; y < img1.Height; y++)
                {
                    for (int x = 0; x < img1.Width; x++)
                    {
                        Color pixel1 = img1.GetPixel(x, y);
                        Color pixel2 = img2.GetPixel(x, y);

                        diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.R - pixel2.R);
                        diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.G - pixel2.G);
                        diff += Math.Abs(pixel1.B - pixel2.B);
                    }
                }

                statusmsg = "diff: {0} %";
                statusmsg = string.Format(statusmsg, 100 * (diff / 255) / (img1.Width * img1.Height * 3));
            }

            // Write status msg to database or make available to other method...

        }

    }
```

Comment: The answer to this question heavily depends on what the threads exactly do, what kind of data they access and how they access it. As you have shown no threads (aside from the main thread), this question can’t really be answered.

Comment: No threads are involved, so why are you asking?

Comment: I added more code to clarify. Basically the goal is to compare 2 or more images that have been uploaded and determine how similar they are. The images will reside on the file system or in some kind of cloud blob storage such as Azure blob storage.