# Detect whether the datagridview image column has the default image

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, vb.net-2010

I have a datagridview with an image column, the Null Value for this column is automatically set as `System.Drawing.Bitmap` in the designer.

Now from the code behind I need to check whether the column is displaying the Default Image or a different one, for the purpose of showing it in an picturebox.

For this I tried using the following code.

```
If Not dgImageList.CurrentRow.Cells("img1").Value Is Nothing Then pctBox.BackgroundImage = dgImageList.CurrentRow.Cells("img1").Value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recomend you to use another column to perform that comparison. Any boolean property (Ex: "return image is null" ), the name of the picture, or something like this.

Because if I have understood your question, you title may be "Compare two images". Then, nothing to "reinvent":
[Compare two images to check if they are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19440001/compare-two-images-to-check-if-they-are-the-same)