# Best way to match a auto part images in a database using C#

Tags: c#, image, detection

Can anyone recommend a method to compare an image taken from a web cam to images stored in a database and display the ones that nearly match?

Answer (score 0):

You might take a look at [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm) where several options are discussed about how to compare images.  It would seem to me that a histogram approach might provide a quick comparison.  Obviously it isn't perfect but it can reduce the candidate set down considerably.