# NSData compare to NSData in percents

Tags: iphone, objective-c, compare, nsdata

I Have 
`NSData *object1` and another `NSData *object2`. How can I compare this objects by what percentage they are similar? For example: Object1 similar to Object2 in - 99%. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Get the bytes in both cases and iterate through checking how many of them are equal.

```
uint8_t* bytes1 = (uint8_t*)[object1 bytes];
uint8_t* bytes2 = (uint8_t*)[object2 bytes];

NSUInteger sameCount = 0;
for (NSUInteger i = 0 ; i < MIN([object1 length], [object2 length]) ; ++i)
{
    if (bytes1[i] == bytes2[i])
    {
        sameCount++;
    }
}

double fractionSame = (double) sameCount / (double) MIN([object1 length], [object2 length]);
```

The above assumes if one data is longer than the other, you don't care about the excess.

Answer (score 1):

It really depends on the logic. If you are, for example, trying to compare images (and their data is stored as NSData) then you need to [write image comparison algorithms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm). If it is some other kind of data, then you need to define that semantics first. If all else fails I think @JeremyP answer should suffice.

Answer (score 0):

There's no such thing for NSData.  You'll need to write your own NSSortDescriptor thing, optimized for how you want to compare the contents of one NSData to another.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSSortDescriptor_Class/Reference/Reference.html