# Image comparision is not working in ios simulator

Tags: iphone, ios, uiimageview

I am developing one application.In that i am doing comparision operation for two images like below

```
 UIImage *actual_image=usrcheck_image.image;
NSData *present_image = UIImagePNGRepresentation(actual_image);
NSData *compare_image = UIImagePNGRepresentation([UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk-1.png"]);

if([present_image isEqualToData:compare_image])
{
   set the checked image
}
else
{
   set the uncheck image.
 }
```

If i run this,check image is changed to uncheck.But uncheck image is not chneged to check image.Everytime else block is executed.So please help me how to compare these two images.This code is working perfectly in device.But the problem is in simulator only.

Comment: See this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7806230/1704346)

Comment: Comparing image data just to change a checkbox state (presumably) is a very bad idea, performance-wise.

Comment: Then how can i chang ethe image of imageview.

Comment: Base question: **why** do you need to perform image comparison?

Answer (score 1):

Try This Code -

Take 2 images of checked and unchecked and assign that images to UIButton.

```
 UIButton *button = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 30);
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"checkedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
[button setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"uncheckedImage.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
button.tag = 1;
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[self.view addSubview:button];
```

And In buttonAction function -

```
selectedBtn.selected = NO;
button.selected = YES;
selectedBtn = button;
```

In .h file just mention

```
UIButton *selectedBtn;
```

Hope It may help you.

Comment: It's somewhat better.But i have to change the image for normal state not for selected state.

Comment: Ok.But may I know why do you need to perform image comparison? Let me know why it is needed so that I will try to solve your problem. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `highlighted` property of `UIImageView`. Set the checked image as `highlightedImage` property, and on the click event set:

```
yourImageView.isHighlighed = !yourImageView.isHighlighed;
```

it will automatically show your image as toggle

Comment: @user1498119:Do you have issue with this ans

Comment: No use just a single image view. set it image property as unselected image. and set it highlighted property as selected image. and when you click on button than in tapped method use yourImageView.isHighlighed = !yourImageView.isHighlighed; this code only, nothing else you have to do more

Answer (score 0):

May be link below can help you

[Objective-C: Comparing an image against another image that has been previously saved](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11216167/objective-c-comparing-an-image-against-another-image-that-has-been-previously-s)

Let me know if this works

Comment: This one also same what iam using.It's works on device but not in simulator.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is, there is no need of comparison of image Data and no need to compare images too,

But if you want to compare images means , just simply do like following

```
if(usrcheck_image.image==[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk-1.png"]) {
    usrcheck_image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"chk-1.png"];
} else {
    usrcheck_image.image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"unchk-1.png"];
}
```

Comment: It's not working in simulator.may be it's work on device.I need to do that one in simulator.

Comment: if your image is present in your project source... surely it will also work in simulator too...