# Finding image in image position, with Keypoint Matching technique

Tags: c#, algorithm, image-processing, opencv, comparison

Hi I looking for solution which find real time positions of template in source image.

I find many theoretical discussions, and in this article [Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm) i found **Keypoint Matching technique**.

Have any one any experiences with this in c# ? Some tests ? Or better some code samples ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Main_Page) it is a C# wrapper that will allow you to use the OpenCV library. In particular, the [features2d](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/files/2.3.0/document/Index.html) library. Finally, [here](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/SURF_feature_detector_in_CSharp) is an example to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

One improvement:

In this time is [EmguCV](http://www.emgu.com/wiki/index.php/Version_History) in version 2.3.x and in this version are some changes.

And one what I found in example above is that, **SURFTracker** is replaced by **Features2DTracker**.

Here some example [SurfDetector](http://code.google.com/p/cam-calib3d/source/browse/trunk/Calib3D.Feature/SurfDetector.cs?r=63)