# How to create a unique fingerprint for an image

Tags: php, c++, delphi

Is there any open source code/library that can find similar images like TinEye does?

Comment: you can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm

Answer (score 4):

There is the google serach api http://code.google.com/apis/imagesearch/ but it is Deprecated.  But that doesn't mean that you can't expect a replacement.  Also doesn't meant there will be.

Yahoo also has one here

http://www.programmableweb.com/api/yahoo-image-search

Those are free.  I would expect the yahoo one to stay up.

Hope that helps. Cheers -Jeremy