# Testing chart rendering

Tags: java, testing, jfreechart

I have some chart rendering tasks that I want to cover with tests. I used svg renderer in my tests. At first run I generate some files. At next runs I want to compare output with first run results. If they are different tests should fail. It was just fine. The issue is that such rendering is platform depended. So that I cannot run same tests on Linux and Windows. I don't like it at all. How can I write cross platform tests for stuff that used JFreeChart?

Comment: Why not compare the SVG files, without rendering?

Comment: @Dmitri I compare new render result with old one. How I can do it without rendering?

Comment: I misunderstood, thought you were rendering the SVG to bitmap images before comparing. You could always save platform-specific test files and detect the platform when testing.

Comment: @Dmitri Ok. I have some module that produces SVG files. In my tests I produce some files using this module. At first run I produce some files. In next runs I want to compare new files to old ones. If there are difference they should fail.

Comment: I'm with you now. So, can you generate the reference files on both platforms, so you can compare the correct one based on where you're running the tests?

Comment: @Dmitri I doesn't like this approach. It can be more than two platform. There can be different behavior on Macs or in other Linux distributions. Anyway, I use Java to write platform independent code. Why I should write tests for each platform/configuration separately?

Comment: Also, just because the two outputs match, that doesn't mean that _either one_ is correct.  I mean, if you pass it data that should result in a chart/image, but due to internal bugs it gives you a blank one, your test wouldn't necessarily be able to detect incorrect behaviour.

Comment: @X-Zero I can watch results myself. But I want to do it only once. On first run. I don't want to verify it for each platform. Also, currently both results are correct. But they are different.

Comment: See also [*Image comparison—fast algorithm*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/843972/230513).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok. I solve this issue. If someone have same issue keep in mind next hints

1. JFreeChart use platform specific fonts by default. So you should distribute your `ttf` font and set it explicitly for each label. You can load font by `Font.createFont`.
2. Use specific locale. You can set default locale for your test by next code `Locale.setDefault(Locale.US);`