# phase correlation 2D (Stitch 2D in ImageJ) for image stitching

Tags: image-processing, opencv, computer-vision, cross-correlation, image-stitching

Now I'm using standard phase correlation for image stitching.
It give normal results, but on hard images it gives wrong result, but Stitch 2D plugin in ImageJ(FIJI) gives good result in the majority of cases.
The algorithm used in plugin described in this paper http://bioinformatics.oxfordjournals.org/content/25/11/1463.full.pdf
But i can't understand it.
"In real images, however,F−1(Q) contains several peaks marking different
translations with high correlation. Moreover, each peak describes eight
different possible translations (in 3D) due to the periodicity of the Fourier
space. To determine the correct shift, we select the n highest local maxima
(3×3×3 neighborhood) from F−1(Q) and evaluate their eight possible
translations by means of cross-correlation on the overlapping area of the
images A,B. The peak with the highest correlation is selected as translation
between the two images. If none of the peaks is above a certain limit the
tiles are assumed to be non-overlapping."
can anyone explain how to implement it?

Comment: If you are using 2-D Phase Correlation I suggest you read introductory material or original papers. Checking the 8 best peaks (for 3-D) with cross correlation is a waste of time.

Comment: it seems that algorithm axplained in "Kuglin,C.D. and Hines,D.C. (1975) The phase correlation image alignment method.
In Proceedings of the IEEE, International Conference on Cybernetics and Society,
pp. 163–165."  but I can't find this paper.

Comment: Here is another important paper by Graham Thomas, http://www.bbc.co.uk/rd/publications/rdreport_1987_11.shtml I think you will find it teaches everything you need.

Comment: I find only some information about filtration in this paper. What if I smooth initial image? it help to filtrate fake peaks? or I must filtrate spatial domain?

Comment: Are you windowing the input to phase correlation ? or does it do it for you ? This is essential.

Comment: No I don't. I find some information here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_window#Hamming_window  but can't understand it.I need to do it before FFT? Also I can't understand what w,n,N in formula's?     code that i use here http://codepaste.ru/9226/

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Window_function ; if you have problem with your code either insert into this question or ask another question.

Comment: I apply Hamming window here the results with window http://rghost.ru/36617449/image.png  without window http://rghost.ru/36617443/image.png .And the max peak has the same coordinate.I use the code
double omega = 2.0*M_PI/(fft_size-1);  
double A= 0.54;
double B= 0.46; 
img1[k].Re= (img1[k].Re)*(A-B*cos(omega*k));
but I don't understand which parameters better, or which window type is better.

Comment: I think jiles de wit has answered your original question. I think you should accept his answer and start a new question about the "hard" images that your code doesn't work with.

Comment: ok. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9377640/phase-correlation-for-image-stitching-using-of-hamming-window

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the quote it looks as if:

1. They use phase correllation to find multiple candidates (*"we select the n highest local maxima (3×3×3 neighborhood) from F−1(Q)"*) for the overlapping segment between two images
2. And then they use some matching in the original image data (*"by means of cross-correlation on the overlapping area of the images A,B."*)
3. To select the best candidate from those(*"The peak with the highest correlation is selected as translation between the two images."*),
4. If that best candidate matches good enough (*"If none of the peaks is above a certain limit the tiles are assumed to be non-overlapping."*).

Comment: yes, I understand it on the level that you explain but I don't understand item 2) the method of "some matching".It seems like they find N best peaks but what to do next?

Comment: By matching I mean that for each peak found in step 1 they then compare the corresponding regions of overlap in image A and B, and determine how similar these two regions are (as they should be if they overlap) they use cross correlation for this matching step (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-correlation). This gives them another number for each peak (the cross correlation coefficient) that is higher if the overlapping pieces in image A and B are more similar. In step 3 they then select the highest of these numbers (i.e. most similar overlapping area).

Comment: Other names for matching are "image comparison" and "template matching". Some techniques (other than cross correlation) are discussed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm

Comment: Since phase correlation is a type of normalised cross correlation, calculating additional correlation values for each peak will not improve the result.

Comment: Phase correlation is calculated on the Fourier transform of the original image data. In step two you use the correlation of the original image data.

Comment: I think it's the same only some difference in normalisation.

Comment: @jiles-de-wit Phase correlation is the normalised cross power spectrum. The CPS is the Fourier Transform pair of cross correlation so calculating the PC is almost the same as calculating cross correlation in the spatial domain. The difference is so small, it wouldn't be worth doing.

Comment: @koan, I know this (it is all coming back to me now), but this is what is done in the paper the orginal question asks about, and they claim it helps. So presumably the small difference is enough of a difference to make a difference. And anyway, I was answering the question (how to implement their technique) not debating its merits.