# phase correlation for image stitching (using of Hamming Window)

Tags: image-processing, fft, fftw, image-stitching, cross-correlation

I use phase correlation for image stitching and it gives good results for most part of my test data. I just stitiching pairs of image left-right and top-bottom(only shift)
But there is some strange behaviour. 
First strange coordinates, I must convert coordinates

```
//if L-R
pt.x= src->width-maxloc.x;
pt.y= src->height-maxloc.y;
if(pt.y>(temp->height/2))
  pt.y= -(maxloc.y+1);
//if T-B
pt.x= src->width-maxloc.x;
pt.y= src->height-maxloc.y;
if(pt.x>(temp->width/2))
  pt.x= -(maxloc.x+1);
```

Then usage of Hamming window it seems that when I use Hamming window for left-right stitching it works better(even for bad cases), but if I use Hamming window for top-bottom it works bad (even in good cases).
And I think I don't need to separate individual cases for L-R and T-B, I expect that phase correlation just give me the global maximum, but it seems that some mistakes in understanding of FFT or phase correlation.
here is the code that I use http://codepaste.ru/9415/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code has a glaring mistake:

```
//if L-R
pt.x= src->width-maxloc.x;
pt.y= src->height-maxloc.y;
if(pt.y>(temp->height/2))
  pt.y= -(maxloc.y+1);
//if T-B
pt.x= src->width-maxloc.x;  // (repeated)
pt.y= src->height-maxloc.y; // <- overwrites previous value
if(pt.x>(temp->width/2))
  pt.x= -(maxloc.x+1);
```

Please can you show the images that you are trying to register.

Comment: no it isn't mistake, I just post code for 2 cases left-right and top-bottom(in real they are in different places).I know relation between images (pairs of images) but dont know the percentage of overlap, so I do phase correlation only for half of images(to reduce computational complexity)
But I don't understand why coordinates must be converted.

i want to achive something like that http://www.xuvtools.org/screenshots

                       I post some examples later.

Comment: Now, I even think I have some mistake in phase correlation code that done using FFTW , here is the code http://codepaste.ru/9423/  , I test it like  phase_correlation2D(img,img,poc) and it gives me (0,0).

Comment: Co-ordinates need to be converted because of the repeating nature of the Fourier transform: translation at -n looks like translation at (max-n). What translation do you expect for this pair of images ?

Comment: for this images (190,1750).
I found some information about zero-padding of images, maybe it helps in my case? I want to stitch image without any prior information about their orientation.

Comment: These 2 images have too little overlap to use PC. Zero padding increases accuracy, not range.

Comment: ImageJ also failed at this pictures, but I have images that have bigger overap. And what if images have diffent size? like on this picture http://www.wedesoft.demon.co.uk/hornetseye-api/images/phasecorrelation.png      
and how in general I can understand what algorithm gives me -n or (max-n) ?

Comment: For different size images or when the overlap is bigger but insufficient you can get phase correlation between cropped areas, e.g. 64x64 block at (500,0) in image 1 with 64x64 block at (0,0) in image 2. This is suitable if you know the approximate layout of images in advance.

Comment: by the way microsoft image composite editor can stitch this type of images, but I don't know what algorithm it use.