# image processing and comparing android app

Tags: java, android, database, mobile, image-processing

I want to create an android app. please consider the following scenario:

Iam standing on a road and in front of me there are two different buildings one is of university and the other one is a factory i then capture images of both the buildings and store these images in my database.

know what i want is when i move my android phone camera back towards the university building it does some image processing and matches the image of university from my database with the university building view in the camera and shows result "image found" and if there is no match in database then my app should output "image not found" please help me how should i start doing this or if you can recommend a good library to do this.

Comment: Must this work in all lighting conditions?  What if you come back days later and the banner on the front of the building has changed?  What if you step 4 inches forward?  Should database images from one camera work with a different camera?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the camera class in android will help you take the image.
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.html

sqlite database can be used to store images
http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/store-imagesfiles-database

and you might need to use some image comparison algorithm to know if they are the same(or almost same) images.
[Image comparison - fast algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm)