# Comparing images with different resolutions

Tags: image, image-processing, hash, comparison

Is there possible to compare two images with different resolutions?

I mean here some algorithmic/programming approach. For instance, now I calculate **hash code from image's byte array** and compare these hash code values. That is work great but fail in case of different resolutions, i.e. images are identical **by eye** but different in it byte content.

For example see my image attaches:
[image][image]

one of it has **72 ppi** but another **96 ppi**. I would like to have **TRUE** value while comparing on equality but now I get **FALSE**. Help please to find correct solution here.

Comment: Maybe create low-res copies of both images (say 128*128, maybe 32*32), and compare these instead? YMMV

Comment: This answer shows some interesting methods http://stackoverflow.com/a/844113/441354

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Two very simple perceptual hashing methods you might give a try before venturing into more complicated territory are based on the Discrete Cosine Transform and the local vs glocal mean of an image:

1. Convert image to grayscale

   1.1 (EDIT) Make your image zero mean
2. Crush your image down to thumbnail size, say [32x32]
3. Run the two dimensional Discrete Cosine Transform
4. Keep the top left [8 x 8], most significant low frequency components
5. Binarize the block, based on the sign of the components
6. Result is a 64 bit hash

And a variant on this theme would be

1. Convert image to grayscale
2. Optionally re-size to a predefined size.
3. Partition the image in a fixed number of blocks
4. Determine the global mean
5. Determine the local mean per block
6. For the hash, write out a 1 or a 0 per block, pending if the local
   mean was larger or smaller than the global mean.

Also, have a look at [phash](http://www.phash.org).

Comment: What is official method name for your first approach? Is there any free implementations in some programming language?

Comment: @Michael Z, I only know them as "perceptual hashing" sorry. phash is opensource, but there are restrictions for commercial usage. Best to talk to them. Good luck.

Comment: Well thanks. But I had some problems with your algo (I have used the first). The lack is in *5.Binarize the block, based on the sign of the components* you have not clarified this process. I have performed binarization based on below/above of zero (0) value, but the correct solution is considering mean value of colors but not zero. This article much helps me: https://www.memonic.com/user/aengus/folder/coding/id/1qVeq

Comment: @Michael Z You are right! I forgot to mention that I make images zero mean.

Comment: @Maurits,I am using the same logic for my Image comparison case. but it fails for the following image whose link I have added in the comment. And the difference is just of a size and nothing else. Link1 = http://www.snapdeal.com/product/park-avenue-green-polyester-regular/674651359945#bcrumbLabelId:745
Link2 = https://www.flipkart.com/park-avenue-formal-sleeveless-self-design-women-s-green-top/p/itmedshpbs2xkth5?pid=TOPEDSHPWZUE5SXW&srno=b_1_51&otracker=browse&lid=LSTTOPEDSHPWZUE5SXWH63N7L

Answer (score 4):

For synthetic images with a few distinct colours I would start with histogram matching.

Basically add up the number of pixels of each colour in each image and divide by the total number of pixels. Then you have a simple float vector as a fingerprint. You can ignore white if you want images with more or less border to count as a match

It's not going to detect the same image with the slices re-arranged, or the text moved down a line but i don't think that is the concern in this case