# What is the starting point for simple image indexing for search tool

Tags: image-processing, indexing, search-engine, go

I'm bulding a small photo gallery website and I need a function that detect duplicate images (don't need to be be 100% accurate, just like Google Image Search).

I'm using a very new language (Golang) so I don't think there is any available library for this out there.

So what is the starting point for me? Please give me some keyword about this. Or if you have any material that is simple and easy to understand, please share me.

Comment: Just checking : you don't want to detect equal files ?

Comment: Have a look at these SO questions on so-called perceptual hash functions: [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154622/comparing-images-with-different-resolutions/10155886#10155886) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm/844113#844113).

Comment: @dystroy yes equal or scaled ass well. Or event some color change but with the same layout!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this [blog post](http://www.hackerfactor.com/blog/index.php?/archives/432-Looks-Like-It.html) is simple and easy to understand.