# how to get md5 hash of an image, without being affected by jpeg compression

Tags: java, algorithm, image-processing

[image: No description]

I have alot of `.jpg` images with some duplicates  (of the same size) that only differ slightly in their jpg comrpession level. I need to make a function that somehow returns the same md5 hash of all similar images based on their colors or color/shape/.. signature and ignore the compression level.

I thought about calculating the color average of each 4 pixels, and write it as 1 pixel into a grid, then use the result to get an md5 signature of the whole image?

I was wondering if there is a better way of doing this, maybe a library or an algorithme that does just this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Detecting if two images are visually identical](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/336067/detecting-if-two-images-are-visually-identical)

Comment: You need to have a look at so called perceptual hashing techniques, or robust fingerprinting. A simple example of the first can be seen here on [stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10154622/comparing-images-with-different-resolutions/10155886#10155886).