# Extracting fainted repeated patterns from an image

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, computer-vision

I have an image that contains repeated fainlty occuring patterns within it. I am interested in extracting only the patterns and turn other features in the image. Is there away to do this using python, especially, opencv or anyother python image library. I have seen the post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49100690/recognition-of-repeated-pattern-in-an-image) but it is not excatly what I am looking for.
[image]

I have tried to convert the image from bgr to hsv, apply different filters like bilateral filter, histogram equalisation and combination of thresholding without any success.

```py
_, thres_image = cv2.threshold(image, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY_INV + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)
image_ycrcb = cv2.CV.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_RGB2YCrCb)
chal_y, _, _ = cv2.split(image_ycrcb)
equ_image = cv2.equalizeHist(chal_y)
```

Comment: input data would help. -- none of those will do anything. you could try locally adaptive thresholding, or subtract a lowpass (gaussian, median, ...) https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGBST.png looks like some "imaginary property protection" watermark to me