# check the same images after flip cards (objective-C)

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, cocoa, nsimage

I have 4 cards and I can flip my cards, I want to check if my images is the same show 2 images and if it's not back the flip,

would you please give me some tutorial or sample code;

Thanks in advance!

Edit:

Here is my images:

```
UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_front.png"];

[self addCardAtX:90 y:120 andFrontImage:img1 andTag:1];
[self addCardAtX:230 y:120 andFrontImage:img1 andTag:1];
[self addCardAtX:90 y:340 andFrontImage:img1 andTag:1];
[self addCardAtX:230 y:340 andFrontImage:img1 andTag:1];



- (void)addCardAtX:(CGFloat)x y:(CGFloat)y andFrontImage:(UIImage *) img1 andTag:(int)tag
{

UIImage *img2= [UIImage imageNamed:@"card_back.png"];


CardView *cv = [[CardView alloc] initWithFrontImage:img1 backImage:img2];


CGRect f = cv.frame;
f.origin.x = x-(f.size.width/2.0);
f.origin.y = y-(f.size.height/2.0);
cv.frame = f;


[self.view addSubview:cv];
}
```

Comment: Yes, use something else other than the images. What you are trying to do is hard. Use the tags or something else.

Comment: @adam: the more tags, more people will see. more answer, fast answer, super answer.

Comment: @Fogmeister do you know any tutorial? for filp card images and compare them

Comment: No, but presumably you have some code that means "load image x" or "load image y" for a specific card. Well use THAT information to see if the cards match, not the images.

Answer (score 1):

You can Compare image by its **NAME or URL/Path**
But in objective-c you can also compare  two objects, By,

```
if ([object1 isEqual:object2])
```

take BOOL variable imgCompare=NO; and check condition

```
if([Imgobject1 isEqual:ImgObject2])
  imgCompare=YES;
else
  imgCompare=NO;
```

Here is best [Question of related discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm) and also check [This Link.](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html)

**Thanks :)**

Answer (score 0):

You can check if images are equal buy using...

```
BOOL imagesAreTheSame = [image1 isEqual:image2];
```