# Game map calibration using java

Tags: java, image, calibration

The goal is to calibrate the game map to a certain point where everything on the map is expected using the Robot class in java to drag and pull the map.

I'll show you an example here:

http://ww4.sinaimg.cn/mw690/9342b99dgw1egmnxql89ij20fc0be767.jpg

Imagine the picture is the whole game map but the rectangle is actually what you can see. we now need to drag the map to the right to make the house appear in the screen.

However calibration is what i need: I want the house to land at a exact location of the screen instead of only in the screen.(pixel specific)

I can't get the whole game map,and my plan is to make java drag the map around and see if they can hit some pixel colors, if it hits then it's calibrated but I don't know how to hit with colors on barely a few pixels (it might be very slow if I try to compare all the pixels).

What's more, I can't make sure before calibration the screen is always focusing on one specific part of the map, ie. screen focus is randomly landed.

I've tried searching some image calibration software like imagej but it seems to only deal with images, not some parts in a game map.

Any idea of you is greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: Because you mention the robot class my guess is your actually "comparing images" not "calibrating" them. Check out this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm theres a boat load of algorithms on there

Comment: IMO, you'd be better off storing the coordinates of any objects in the image you're interested in.  Trying to process the image in real-time seems rather inefficient.