# How to compare between two images using VB.net?

Tags: vb.net, screenshot

I have a small bitmap image and I will do a screenshot. I need to find whether the small image is the screenshot. How I can compare two bitmap images? and then return the coordinates.

If it is MATLAB, (NOTE: I need VB.net)

What my plan is this

```
screenshot
for x_screen = 1: screen_width_x
     for y_screen = 1: screen_col_y 
      for x_pic = = 1: pic_width_x
       for y_pic = = 1: pic_col_y
       if screenshot(x_screen, y_screen) != pic(x_pic , y_pic)
       break
       end
    end
    xx = (x_screen)
    yy = (y_screen)
    end
    end
```

Answer (score 2):

[See  Image comparison if you want something advanced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm) Also you can look for machine learning techniques for such tasks.

Here is naive solution and not optimized one (plus it is better to do such tasks in native code):

**Plus Note that it is better to check this with bmp files. otherwise it will not handle problem**

```
Private Function FindSubImg2(img As Bitmap, subimg As Bitmap) As Point
    If (img.Width - subimg.Width < 0) Or (img.Height - subimg.Height < 0) Then Return Nothing 
    Dim stepxLen As Integer = img.Width - subimg.Width
    Dim stepyLen As Integer = img.Height - subimg.Height 
    Dim coor As Point
    Dim match As Boolean = False

    For oy As Integer = 0 To stepyLen
    For ox As Integer = 0 To stepxLen
            match = True 
            For x As Integer = 0 To subimg.Width - 1
                For y As Integer = 0 To subimg.Height - 1
                    'actually here we do not need ToArgb method. But it will skip unneeded Color comparisions
                    If img.GetPixel(x + ox, y + oy).ToArgb <> subimg.GetPixel(x, y).ToArgb Then
                        match = False
                        Exit For 'we can use goto operator instead of double exit for 
                    End If
                Next
                If match = False Then Exit For
            Next
            If match = True Then
                coor.X = ox
                coor.Y = oy
                Return coor
            End If 
        Next
    Next

    Return New Point(-1, -1)
End Function

Private Function FindSubImg(a As Bitmap, b As Bitmap) As Point

    Dim subimg As Bitmap
    Dim img As Bitmap

    If (a.Height <= b.Height AndAlso a.Width <= b.Width) Then
        subimg = a : img = b
        Return FindSubImg2(img, subimg)

    ElseIf (a.Height > b.Height AndAlso a.Width > b.Width) Then
        subimg = b : img = a
        Return FindSubImg2(img, subimg)
    Else
        Return New Point(-1, -1)
    End If


End Function
```

Usage:

```
Dim p As Point = FindSubImg(New Bitmap("A.bmp"), New Bitmap("B.bmp"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
Public Function CompareImages(ByVal img1 As Bitmap, ByVal img2 As Bitmap) As Boolean
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim j As Integer

    For i = 0 To img1.Width - 1
        For j = 0 To img2.Height - 1
            If img1.GetPixel(i, j) <> img2.GetPixel(i, j) Then
                Return False
            End If
        Next
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

sample call:

```
CompareImages(New Bitmap("f:\img1.bmp"), New Bitmap("f:\img2.bmp"))
```