# What is the simplest way to check if two images are the same?

Tags: bitmap, comparison, pixel, photo, repeat

I'm not talking titles / name, I mean pixel analyzation or perhaps bitmapping... perhaps an OCR?

I need to reduce the server usage by not using duplicate media so if a person is trying to upload a photo that is already on the server uploaded by someone else, that photo will not be uploaded.

Comment: You don't know if they are the same untill you chech all pixels :)
But checking 100 random pixels would be ok.

Comment: I had this thought of laying two pictures over each other and if the photos are exactly the same then you would get the first photo times two right? I don't know if that makes sense / is possible but would be cool / simple.

Comment: Try reading this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know about the what technology you are using.

But, I believe you may use md5 check for that. MD5 check are a good way to solve file comparison and it has for a lot of technologies.

Comment: how is that on overhead though? If you had a thousand people uploading at once and each photo has to be checked, is that dumb? Maybe I could accept the photo/file first, then check later perhaps when the network traffic is lower, for duplicates to conserve on storage?

Comment: You could save the md5 text value in another database's table thus you could check that after for a thousand times with  a good performance. The relationship between two (picture x md5 text) could be by foreign key (for a ER model).

Comment: Probably this won't work due to different time and date or am I mistaken?

Comment: It could be useful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm

Comment: thanks for the replies. When I reach this stage, I'll decide if it is even worth implementing or not eg. just buy more storage.

Comment: Sure, but my regard about that is to us keep in our minds "The software should do its goals spending less resources as possible". It is a good approach to us consider as software engineers.

Comment: I was thinking, if you inverted an image then overlayed two images that are supposed to be the same then you would get a blank image right? Not sure if it would be white or black.