# Find similar Image uing matlab or Java

Tags: java, matlab, image-processing, boofcv

[image]

From the below image i want to compare a particular product from the image stored in my DB.

Example

If i want to compare the Vim soap image and the below image. I need to check whether the vim soap is available in the below image.

---

Can anyone help me for this problem.
If any procedure or steps to perform this type of operation using Matlab or Java.

Comment: there are many ways to do this ; FAST, RANSAC, perceptual hashing. you might want to start looking here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm

Comment: Not an exact duplicate, but it has a lot of concepts that will get you started.  Read that post to get a good background on the idea of object / shape recognition, as that is what you are ultimately after.