# Duplicate image detection algorithms in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, algorithm, image-processing

i am looking for a similar image detection algorithm in iOS. I already have one which compares the pixel components and detect similar images based on that, but it is not up to the mark. Can any one suggests better algorithms/methods in terms of accuracy and speed which could possibly be implemented in iOS.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What about your other algorithm is "not up to the mark"? We don't know anything about the other algorithm you have, so saying that you want one that is similar but better doesn't mean much to us

Comment: It may also be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/843972/image-comparison-fast-algorithm?rq=1

Comment: @KevinWells it is just picking pixels in same location from both images and compare the color components.  Now i am going to try the possibility of phash. i will comment my results here. Anyway thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

dHash does a decent job in identifying the similar images.

I have used [CocoaimageHashing](https://github.com/ameingast/cocoaimagehashing) for converting the images to hash values and then compare.