# Best way to scale images for finding similarity?

Tags: image-processing, similarity

I need to calculate the color histogram of images in order to get a feature for finding similarity between images.
(description: https://stackoverflow.com/a/844113/5142270 and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Color_histogram).

The only problem I am facing is in deciding how to scale the images so that they will have the same number of pixels. Is there a standard image size(in pixels) that is used by researchers for this purpose, when there are thousands of images that can be of any dimension? I tried searching a lot on how to scale the images, but was unable to find out what was supposed to be done.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using [pyramids](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pyramid_(image_processing)).

You basically don't have 1 'golden number' of pixels, but you do your feature finding on an image 1/2 the size, and 1/4 and 1/8 and so on, so your feature detection will not be size dependent.