# Image Recognition and match

Tags: xamarin.forms, image-recognition

Is there any sample or reference available which I can refer to do the following task.

I want to match user's face with his already stored pic. So when I open camera in front of the person, it should get the data from the current camera object and match with the stored one on the server. 
I already have Xamarin.Forms application which currently searches users based on their ID numbers and it displays their pics too. Now I want to use face recognition api to match with the already existing images.

I tried Microsoft's Cognitive services but that is limited and paid.

Comment: Do you refer to this https://westus.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/563879b61984550e40cbbe8d/operations/563879b61984550f3039523a( Face - Verify of Microsoft )?

Answer (score 0):

Comparing pictures and face recognition are not much the same thing. Face recognition is a far more advanced technique to match 2 faces.
You could try to match 2 faces with comparing pictures with implementing an algorithm with [these approaches](https://stackoverflow.com/a/844113/3495516) (histogram, hash..)
I would recommend you to reconsider if you really need face recognition in your app. If yes, go for commerce/paid solutions like Microsoft's Cognitive services and you will spare yourself lot of study/time/money than implementing an own or open source solution.